# How do I know the URL of a web app on my machine?

Tags: java, javascript, websphere

So I just got internship at this company, and they would like me to complete a project(Web application) which someone else did but didn't finish two years ago. But the person didn't leave any documentation about this web app. Right now I would like to run and test this web app, but I couldn't get it started.

So it's running on WebSphere Application Server in IBM Rational Application Developer, the code is written in java and javascript. (I could start the server, but I don't know where to go and open up the web app)

Sorry I'm really new to this, questions might be stupid, appreciate any help:)

Comment: On the host machine, access it at `localhost`.

Comment: And check the deployment descriptor to see what the context name is.

Comment: I would start from context.xml (or) web.xml if any in that project and server logs, based on your comment that you are able to deploy and run.

Comment: or go to admin console. find the deployed app and there should be an option to open it ( should open welcome page listed in deployment descriptor /web.xml )

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what port it's running on? You should be able to access it from a web browser on the host machine by going to

```
http://127.0.0.1:XX
```

where XX is the port in question. If you don't know, try 80 - that's the default HTTP port and it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The default websphere web port is 9080, so try `http://localhost:9080/`

Comment: If you don't know the context the application uses you won't get far with just the hostname + port

Answer (score 0):

> So it's running on WebSphere Application Server in IBM Rational Application Developer

and

> I could start the server

Assuming you are able to start the server *via RAD* as I assume from the above and you are able to publish the app to WebSphere via RAD, you should then be able to right click on the project folder and choose "Run on Server."  It will walk you through publishing the app to the server and will then launch a browser to the index page or URL via the context path and web project settings.  You can have RAD use an embedded browser (default) or adjust it to launch an external browser via Preferences -> Web Browser.

To manually check where a webapp will be deployed you can either check application.xml (if you have one) OR you can right click on the project root folder in RAD, choose Properties, and Web Project Settings.  The context path is in a field there.

Run-On-Server will show you both server/hostname (usually localhost), port, and application context path in one operation.